# Ionic build for iOS - ionic-native/core version issues

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, npm, ionic3, ionic-native

When trying to add the iOS platform to an Ionic3 project, I get an odd error that a newer version of ionic-native/core doesn't satisfy reqs which are all older versions.  I have the latest core - how do I resolve this so I can add the platform?

```
ionic cordova build ios
> cordova platform add ios --save
Using cordova-fetch for cordova-ios@~4.3.1

Error: Failed to fetch platform cordova-ios@~4.3.1
Probably this is either a connection problem, or platform spec is incorrect.
Check your connection and platform name/version/URL.
Error: npm: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
npm ERR! Darwin 16.7.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/Users/michael/Developer/Ionic/Mobile/node_modules/.bin/npm" "install" "cordova-ios@~4.3.1" "--production" "--save-exact"
npm ERR! node v6.11.2
npm ERR! npm  v2.15.12
npm ERR! code EPEERINVALID

npm ERR! peerinvalid The package @ionic-native/core@4.3.3 does not satisfy its siblings' peerDependencies requirements!
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer @ionic-native/camera@4.3.3 wants @ionic-native/core@^4.2.0
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer @ionic-native/camera-preview@3.14.0 wants @ionic-native/core@^3.6.0
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer @ionic-native/card-io@4.3.3 wants @ionic-native/core@^4.2.0
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer @ionic-native/device@4.3.3 wants @ionic-native/core@^4.2.0
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer @ionic-native/device-motion@4.3.3 wants @ionic-native/core@^4.2.0
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer @ionic-native/diagnostic@3.14.0 wants @ionic-native/core@^3.6.0
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer @ionic-native/file@3.14.0 wants @ionic-native/core@^3.6.0
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer @ionic-native/file-transfer@4.3.2 wants @ionic-native/core@^4.2.0
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer @ionic-native/flashlight@3.14.0 wants @ionic-native/core@^3.6.0
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer @ionic-native/geolocation@3.14.0 wants @ionic-native/core@^3.6.0
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer @ionic-native/image-picker@3.14.0 wants @ionic-native/core@^3.6.0
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer @ionic-native/insomnia@3.14.0 wants @ionic-native/core@^3.6.0
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer @ionic-native/keyboard@3.14.0 wants @ionic-native/core@^3.6.0
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer @ionic-native/keychain-touch-id@4.3.2 wants @ionic-native/core@^4.2.0
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer @ionic-native/launch-navigator@3.14.0 wants @ionic-native/core@^3.6.0
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer @ionic-native/media-capture@3.14.0 wants @ionic-native/core@^3.6.0
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer @ionic-native/network@3.14.0 wants @ionic-native/core@^3.6.0
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer @ionic-native/photo-library@3.14.0 wants @ionic-native/core@^3.6.0
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer @ionic-native/rollbar@4.3.2 wants @ionic-native/core@^4.2.0
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer @ionic-native/screen-orientation@3.14.0 wants @ionic-native/core@^3.6.0
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer @ionic-native/splash-screen@3.10.2 wants @ionic-native/core@^3.6.0
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer @ionic-native/sqlite@3.14.0 wants @ionic-native/core@^3.6.0
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer @ionic-native/status-bar@3.10.2 wants @ionic-native/core@^3.6.0
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer @ionic-native/transfer@3.14.0 wants @ionic-native/core@^3.6.0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is due to an odd issue with npm not being installed *locally* (as opposed to globally).

To fix, run `npm install npm` in the directory where you're trying to add the platform. This will also update the packages to the correct peer dependency version.

Then run `ionic cordova platform add ios` again.